# How to get relational data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.4` where I'm having two models `Companies` and `Contact` I'm having a relation of `belongsTo` in `Contact model` something like this:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Companies');
}
```

Now while fetching the contact data I want to fetch `company name`, individually I can do `Contact::find(1)->company->name`, But I've a table to show these I want to pass `company_name/companyName` when I call `Contact::all()` or something, any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: not sure what do you need here

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya I'm querying the complete set of table of contacts which has company_id as per relationship, I want to have the one more data attribute which holds company_name in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to fetch all the contacts with their companies.

You can use with() for that:

```
Contact::with('company')->get();
```

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I'm getting company null

Comment: So you are getting a null result for the above query?